# Salesforce Rest API Response Beans

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

I am migrating our salesforce soap communications to rest API's in which i have to make some DescribeLayout calls.

Do we have any defined java response beans for rest API calls of salesforce, because DescribeLayout call contains huge data. Creating my own beans is a cumbersome process.

(i was trying to use com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeLayout from partner API, but this doesn't have details field inside DescribeLayoutComponent, so i am not able to use the existing beans from sales force partner API )

is there any existing jar available for all response beans ? or do we have to create all response beans our self ?

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that Java beans (meaning Java classes with fixed name and type properties) are not a good way to go when consuming JSON. Instead use one of the [JSON packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) available for Java. You can create a small number of `Enum` classes to hold the names of the fields that are important to your logic and ignore the rest of the fields.